# How can I add left aligned text to an equation?

Tags: equations, align

I have a document I am trying to copy to learn TeX. Here is what I have encountered:[image] How can I have the "or" in the equation. This is what I have right now:

```
\[ f = ma; \] 
But $a$ is the change in velocity,

\[ f = m \frac{dv}{dt};\]
\[ f = m  \frac{d^2y}{dt^2};\]
```

Edit: Trying out Stefan's answer
[image]

Comment: Related Questions: [AMS align: Left aligned text/math plus multicolumn align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/ams-align-left-aligned-text-math-plus-multicolumn-align), [Left-aligned text inside an equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59995/left-aligned-text-inside-an-equation).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use the `amsmath` package and the commands `\text{...}` for text in the formula or `\intertext{...}` for text between the lines of multi-line formulas. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  f &= ma;\\ \intertext{But $a$ is the change in velocity} 
  f &= m \frac{dv}{dt};\\ \intertext{or} 
  f &= m  \frac{d^2y}{dt^2};
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

One advantage of `align*` to `\[ ... \]` is that you can align the equations on relation symbols.

If you wish to put *or* in the same line, you could use `\text` and `flalign*` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
  && f &= ma;&\\ \text{or} && f &= m \frac{dv}{dt};&\\ \text{or}  &&f &= m  \frac{d^2y}{dt^2};
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image: flalign example]

Comment: & is used both for specifying the alignment position and as column separator, alternating. In columns of formulas, &= means that at = would be aligned, a following & would end the column, like in a table. && has been used to skip a column, i.e. to create an empty column.

Comment: `\intertext{}` is simple to use! I found the linespacing too big and had to tweak it with `\\[-3ex]`, but far easier than fiddling with multiple ampersands.