# How can I break an align environment for a paragraph?

Tags: amsmath, align, paragraphs

I would like to have two displayed equations, broken by a short paragraph, but with aligned equal signs (as if using the `align` environment).  Is there some way to "break" the `align` environment temporarily?

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1665/627).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
\begin{align}
a &= 1 \\
\intertext{and}
b &= 2
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 23):

An alternative which requires less vertical spacing than `\intertext` is `\shortintertext`, provided by the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% automatically loads amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    ax + b &= 0 \\
\shortintertext{and}
    ab &= x
\end{align}
in comparison with
\begin{align}
    ax + b &= 0 \\
\intertext{and}
    ab &= x
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 11):

`\intertext` and `\shortintertext` are the correct solution if you are able to place all the content within one `align` environment.  If for some reason you need to have alignment across two different `align` type environments, you can use

```
\makebox[<length>][<l|r|c>]{<text>}
```

to place the `<text>` in a box of width `<length>` and placed within that box with `l`, `r`, or `c` alignment.  The appropriate `<length>` can be determined via `\widthof` from the [the `calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc).

Below I have defined `\WidestLeftHandSide` and `\WidestRightHandSide`, and applied `r` alignment to the left hand side of the first equation in the second `align`, and an `l` alignment to the right hand side.  This adjustment only needs to be applied once to both side.  This yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\WidestLeftHandSide}{\tan^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta}%
\newcommand*{\WidestRightHandSide}{1 + \tan^2 \theta}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \tan^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta &= 1 + \tan^2 \theta\\
    \implies \cos^2 \theta &= 1 - \sin^2 \theta
\end{align*}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris diam quam, cursus vel porttitor eget, posuere non mauris. Suspendisse potenti. Sed in vestibulum augue. Nullam eu est ante.
\begin{align*}
    \makebox[\widthof{$\WidestLeftHandSide$}][r]{$E$} &= \makebox[\widthof{$\WidestRightHandSide$}][l]{$mc^2$}\\
F &= ma
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Plain: `$$ \eqalignno{ ax+b&=1\cr\noalign{\hbox{and}} ab&=x } $$\bye`.