# Floating lines in align environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

I'm using the `align` environment to align some equations, and I would like to insert some comments between them. The problem is that I'm using `&` to align the equals, and because my comments don't contain some, they make the equations shift to the right.

For example :

```
\begin{align*}
   1 &=& 3 - 2 \\
   \text{And because 2 = 1 + 1} \\
     &=& 3 - 1 - 1
 \end{align*}
```

Okay, this is a stupid example but the problem is the equals will be aligned after the comment "and because...".
Do you have any idea of how I could tell LaTeX to "ignore" the comment and make it "float"?

Comment: this is very like the question [how-can-i-break-an-align-environment-for-a-paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9577/)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). For future questions, please keep in mind that while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\intertext` in place of `\text`. See page 7 of the [amsmath package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf).

Comment: and if `\intertext` leave too much space above and below, `mathtools` have a shorter version: `\shortintertext`. One useful biproduct of both, a page break is allowed at both inserted texts