# Aligning \text{} on the left

Tags: align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I break an align environment for a paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9577/how-can-i-break-an-align-environment-for-a-paragraph)

I am new here, and quite new to LaTeX. I did search for an answer to this as I think it should be trivial, but I didn't find the answer yet. I have something like

```
\begin{align*}
y &= mx + c \\
\text{some text here. So} \\
c &= y-mx \\
\text{but } \\
1+2 &\neq 2 \\
\text{Finally} \\
3 &= 1+2\\
\end{align*}
```

My question is: How to I make all the `\text{}` be aligned on the left instead of the middle? Sorry for my ignorance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I would simply put the text out of the `align` environment.

Comment: Use `\intertext{}`, or `\shortintertext{}`.  `shortintertext` requires [the `mathtools` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

Comment: @Corentin Thank you ! But if I take the text out of the environment, now do I make all the equations align ?

Comment: This question seems very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9577/how-can-i-break-an-align-environment-for-a-paragraph. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: @Joe King Sorry, I had not understood what you meant. Then the answer by Peter Grill works.

Comment: @egreg thank you, you are correct, the answer to the question you linked to does answer my question, but I would never have thought of searching for "break an align environment for a paragraph". In my (probably naive) opinion, if someone is looking for an answer to this problem they would be more likely to search for the question I have worded. It's great that there exists an answer already, but if someone (like me) can't find it, then it's not so useful (to them). Thanks again !

Comment: @JoeKing The purpose of keeping a duplicate question with a pointer to the other one is exactly that somebody may have the same thought as you, so they can find this question and be redirected. So even duplicates are useful. Welcome again!

Comment: @egreg sorry I misunderstood. I thought you intended to delete my question entirely. My bad !