# Regular text between equations in math align mode

Tags: math-mode

I am using the `align` environment to create aligned numbered equations. I would like to add some regular text in between some equations (for the purpose of explaining the next step). Something like this:

```
                   f(x) = abc (1)
                        = def (2)
We now apply the mathematic property of foobar to achieve a new form.
                        = xyz (3)
```

I have tried the following:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{align}
    f(x)    &= abc\\
            &= def\\
\text{Using the property of logarithms that $x^{\log_x y} = y$, we can rewrite $P(w)$ to be $e^{\log P(w)}$.}\\ 
            &= xyz
\end{align}
```

Which produces this output:

[image]

I would like:

1. The text line to be centered (not aligned to the left of the `=` sign)
2. The text line not to have an equation number.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please. Give us a code that compiles directly.

Comment: `\intertext` is made for that kind of thing, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9577/how-can-i-break-an-align-environment-for-a-paragraph/9586#9586

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways, using `\clap` or `\shortintertext`, both from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    f(x) &= abc\\
            &= def\\
\clap{Using the property of logarithms that $x^{\log_x y} = y$, we can rewrite $P(w)$ to be $e^{\log P(w)}$.}\notag\\
            &= xyz
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    f(x) &= abc\\
            &= def\\
\shortintertext{\centering Using the property of logarithms that $x^{\log_x y} = y$, we can rewrite $P(w)$ to be $e^{\log P(w)}$.}
            &= xyz
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why not the standard `\intertext` ?

Comment: The vertical spacing is a bit too large for my taste. Of course that's a personal matter. There's also the optional argument of  `\intertext` provided by `nccmath`.