# flushing lines in gather environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, subequations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add left aligned text to an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/how-can-i-add-left-aligned-text-to-an-equation)

I need to write a system with sub-items looking like this:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
\text{
{\textit{First Block Name}}
}\notag
\\
\begin{cases}\label{eq:first:block}   
A = B & \text{if } C\\
A = D & \text{if } E
\end{cases}
\\
\text{
{\textit{Second Block Name}}
}\notag
\\
\begin{cases}\label{eq:second:block}   
F = G & \text{if } H\\
F = I & \text{if } J
\end{cases}
\\
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
```

but I'd really like to have the block names flushed left (by this code they are centered), while maintaining the "real" equation blocks centered.

any not too elaborate suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.