# Vertical space command which is between \intertext and \shortintertext

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, amsmath, mathtools

Is there a way to define a command like `\notsoshortintertext` with two parameters to define the vertical space before and after it?

The problem I have is that `\intertext` is to wide on a specific page resulting in a poor page break. And with the `\shorintertext` I get an underfull vbox. So I would like to tune the vertical space at that point. I've tried to find the definition for `\shortintertext`, but wasn't able to understand the quite cryptic definition in the mathtools.dtx.

Comment: You could also consider using this technique: [How can I add left aligned text to an equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1665/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no spacing is still too much, you can use negative spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\adjintertext}[3]% #1=above skip, #2=below skip, #3=text
{\ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
  \noalign{%
    %\penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\belowdisplayskip
    \vskip-\lineskiplimit      % CCS
    \vskip\normallineskiplimit % CCS
    \vskip#1
     \vbox{\normalbaselines
       \ifdim
         \ifdim\@totalleftmargin=\z@
           \linewidth
         \else
           -\maxdimen
         \fi
       =\columnwidth
      \else \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
      \fi
      \noindent#3\par}%
    %\penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayskip%
    \vskip-\lineskiplimit      % CCS
    \vskip\normallineskiplimit % CCS
    \vskip#2
 }}%
\MHInternalSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x &= a\\
\adjintertext{0pt}{0pt}{no spacing}
y &= b\\
\adjintertext{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}{big spacing}
z &= c
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: variable spacing]