# What is the vertical spacing caused by the \intertext or \shortintertext command?

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\intertext{what is the vertical spacing here?} \\[-30pt] 1+2 \\
=3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

There is an automatic vertical gap that the `\intertext` command inserts. I would like to know how many pts that gap is to exactly get rid of it with the `\\[...]` command explicit since manually adjusting this height gives me the freedom I require. -30pts is close, but it appears no integer value works and the ams manual doesn't specify the exact spacing of the `intertext` command.

Comment: Related: [Vertical space command which is between `\intertext` and `\shortintertext`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280819/5764)

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I add left aligned text to an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1665/5764)

Comment: use of `\intertext` here is simply user error, using negative spacing will in general cause it to over-print the equation. It is not that `\intertext` adds vertical space, it is that it adds a line of text _after_ the equation. If you want to add text within the equation then you should use `\text` or similar commands.

Comment: It's not technically align* since it uses flalign*, but I will give it a try tomorrow and see if it works, doesn't seem like a large change.

Comment: The duplication suggestion here seemed reasonable to me on the basis of this being an 'XY question': asking about a technical aspect with the ultimate aim being to address a wider layout issue. However, as you are clear that you really do require only detail of the technical aspect, I've reopened. I suggest you edit the question to make the focus absolutely explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add `\showoutput` to your code, you can see the vertical spaces added by TeX to construct the output page. So,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\showoutput
\begin{align*}
  top \\
  \intertext{intertext}
  bottom
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

yields in your `.log`:

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\kern -72.26999
..\vbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 72.26999fil
...\kern -72.26999
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 345.0fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
......\glue 0.0
......\hbox(0.0+794.96999)x0.0
.......\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted 794.96999
........\kern 0.0
........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
....\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
....\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 457.95108fil
...\write-{}
...\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
...\glue(\topskip) 10.0
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 330.0fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\glue -3.0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 6.60004
...\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x187.49423, display
....\glue(\tabskip) 157.50575
....\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x29.98848, glue set 16.49889fil
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x0.0
......\vbox(8.39996+3.60004)x0.0
.......\kern 0.0
.......\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x0.0
........\rule(8.39996+3.60004)x0.0
.....\hbox(6.15079+1.94444)x13.4896
......\mathon
......\hbox(6.15079+1.94444)x13.4896
.......\OML/cmm/m/it/10 t
.......\OML/cmm/m/it/10 o
.......\OML/cmm/m/it/10 p
......\mathoff
....\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
....\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x0.0
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
......\mathon
......\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
......\mathoff
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\tabskip) 157.50575
....\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x-157.50575
.....\kern -157.50575
....\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue 0.0
...\penalty 0
...\glue 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 4.72137
...\vbox(6.67859+0.0)x345.0
....\hbox(6.67859+0.0)x345.0, glue set 307.19437fil
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.....\kern-0.27779
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 r
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
.....\penalty 10000
.....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 6.60004
...\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x187.49423, display
....\glue(\tabskip) 157.50575
....\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x29.98848
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x0.0
......\vbox(8.39996+3.60004)x0.0
.......\kern 0.0
.......\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x0.0
........\rule(8.39996+3.60004)x0.0
.....\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x29.98848
......\mathon
......\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x29.98848
.......\OML/cmm/m/it/10 b
.......\OML/cmm/m/it/10 o
.......\OML/cmm/m/it/10 t
.......\OML/cmm/m/it/10 t
.......\OML/cmm/m/it/10 o
.......\OML/cmm/m/it/10 m
......\mathoff
....\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
....\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x0.0
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
......\mathon
......\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
......\mathoff
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\tabskip) 157.50575
....\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x-157.50575
.....\kern -157.50575
....\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue 0.0
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayskip) 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\glue -3.60004
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.55556
..\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0
...\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
...\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 170.0fil
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
.\kern 0.0
.\kern -633.0
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\kern -72.26999
..\vbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 72.26999fil
...\kern -72.26999
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 345.0fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
......\glue 0.0
......\hbox(0.0+794.96999)x0.0
.......\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, shifted 794.96999
........\kern 0.0
........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\kern 633.0
```

It might not be that easy to see, but between `top` and `intertext` there is

```
...\glue 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 4.72137
```

and between `intertext` and `bottom` there is

```
...\glue 10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 6.60004
```

These are the vertical skips inserted between the constructions. `10.0 plus 2.0 minus 5.0` both represent `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` which can stretch depending where the `align` fits within the regular text block construction. The definition of `\intertext` inside [`amsmath.dtx`](//mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.dtx) provides mention of these skips.

Soooooo... you can get rid of them using

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  top \\[\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\baselineskip]
  \intertext{intertext} \\[\dimexpr-\belowdisplayskip-\baselineskip]
  bottom
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

However, if the intent is just to make a "comment on the left side of an equation", you could probably also do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{zref-savepos,eso-pic}

\newcounter{lc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leftcomment}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{lc}
  \ifmeasuring@\else
    \zsaveposx{comment-\thelc}% Current location x
  \fi
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\zposx{comment-\thelc}sp-\zposx{textblock}sp][l]{#1}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtTextLowerLeft{\zsaveposx{textblock}}}% Left margin of text block

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  top \\[\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\baselineskip]
  \intertext{intertext} \\[\dimexpr-\belowdisplayskip-\baselineskip]
  bottom
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
                           f(x) &= ax^2 \leftcomment{intertext1} \\
  \leftcomment{intertext2} g(x) &= bx \tag{eq2}                  \\
                           h(x) &= c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The idea being [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) is to capture the location of the text block left margin, while [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module allows us to capture the coordinate of a *label* using TeX's `\label`-`\ref` system. Since we use the latter, you'll have to compile twice with every change of the labels.

Comment: +1 for `\showoutput` and not falling back to TikZ to achieve just some positioning :-)

Comment: So I'm having trouble figuring out what is going on here. What is the final answer for \intertext?

Comment: Note that your sample doesn't work correctly with the `nccmath` package, as requested by the OP.

Comment: @siracusa: True, and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Ok, so once again, could you explicitly state the exact, *final* spacing in pts? Because otherwise this just doesn't answer the question, it is much too convoluted when the answer should just be one number.

Comment: @user14554: Without [`nccmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/nccmath) it's `25pt`.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help and patience. Is there anything in particular that nccmath does? Does it add an extra 5pts or 3pts? Should it just be taken out entirely? All I remember ncc doing is adding the `\fleqn`, which I don't need if I can use \\[-25pt] or flalign.

Comment: @user14554: I couldn't resolve the vertical space with using [`nccmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/nccmath), so I'm not sure. You can do without it, since [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `fleqn` and `flalign`.

Comment: Do you know how "flush left" align somehow ends up forcing everything to align on the right-side of the page? That doesn't make sense to me if it is supposed to force text to be left-aligned. I guess it wasn't a solution after all.

Comment: @user14554: You often have to add a `&` on the right-hand side.

Comment: @user14554: It is actually `25pt plus 2pt minus 5pt` in standard 10pt document, which means that the space can be stretched to up to `27pt` and shrunk down to `20pt` if this would improve the overall page layout. The distance between the `\intertext` line and the lines above/below it actually depends on other contents on the page.

Comment: @Werner: I think `\glueexpr` is more appropriate here than `\dimexpr` because with that the stretch will also be cancelled out.

Comment: In which location around or inside of an align environment do you use `\glueexpr`?

Comment: @user14554: I don't use `\glueexpr`. Instead, I used `\dimexpr`. However, `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` are actually glue expressions that can shrink or expand, depending on the content of the document on the page the `align` appears in. Specifically, as Circumscribe mentions, `\abovedisplayskip` (and `\belowdisplayskip`) has a "length" of `10pt plus 2pt minus 5pt`. So that "length" can be as short as `5pt` (`10pt minus 5pt`) or as long as `12pt` (`10pt plus 2pt`). `\glueexpr` keeps the "glue" (the `plus` and `minus` parts) while `\dimexpr` removes them...

Comment: @user14554: ... you seemed interested in a fixed value rather than an explanation, hence my suggestion to use `25pt` (which was `10pt` for `\abovedisplayskip`/`\belowdisplayskip` without the glue + `15pt` for `\baselineskip`). With the glue, it would be anything between `20pt` (`10pt` + `15pt minus 5pt`) and `27pt` (`10pt` + `15pt plus 2pt`).

Comment: See the problem is it shouldn't be a "range" of values, my lines aren't in several places at once like some quantum superposition, it is one finite length, it should just be one value and then that's it. So all this glue and displayskip just doesn't help.

Comment: @user14554: TeX was written with the optimal layout of paragraph and math content in mind. Lines are read in and than spacing is adjusted so that the typesetting is mathematically optimal. In order for this optimality to exist, some stretch is required between word, math content and other things so that adjustments can be made to improve the layout. It's an essential part of TeX. If you want to remove this, specifically for equations, then you can add `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{\dimexpr\abovedisplayskip}` (likewise for `\belowdisplayskip` and others) to your preamble...

Comment: @user14554: ... it'll remove the "flexible spacing" that you loath. Removal of this in other areas within the document may result in bad alignment. Similar to comparing `\raggedright` with the regular typesetting of paragraphs (`\justifying` if you're using [`ragged2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e)). Of course, you're not forced to use (La)TeX...