# How can I define this new math mode environment with comma-separated keyval options?

Tags: math-mode, macros, environments, key-value

My MWE using LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[oneside,DIV=12]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \adjintertext custom spacing \intertext macro (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280847/228055)
    \MHInternalSyntaxOn
    \newcommand{\adjintertext}[3]% #1=above skip, #2=below skip, #3=text
    {\ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
      \noalign{%
        %\penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\belowdisplayskip
        \vskip-\lineskiplimit      % CCS
        \vskip\normallineskiplimit % CCS
        \vskip#1
        \vbox{\normalbaselines
            \ifdim
            \ifdim\@totalleftmargin=\z@
                \linewidth
            \else
                -\maxdimen
            \fi
            =\columnwidth
            \else \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
            \fi
        \noindent#3\par}%
        %\penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayskip%
        \vskip-\lineskiplimit      % CCS
        \vskip\normallineskiplimit % CCS
        \vskip#2
    }}%
    \MHInternalSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}

\lipsum[1][1-6]
\begin{flalign*}
& \text{For any numbers \(a\)}
&& \tag{P'10} \\
%%%%% the part related to the question %%%%%
\adjintertext{0pt}{12pt}{\centering%
  $\begin{alignedat}{2}
     & \text{(i) }   & a &= b, \\
     & \text{(ii) }  & a &< b, \\
     & \text{(iii) } & b &< a.
  \end{alignedat}$%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\) and \(b < c\), then \(a < c\).}
&& \tag{P'11} \\
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\), then \(a + c < b + c\).}
&& \tag{P'12} \\
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\) abd \(0 < c\), then \(ac < bc\).}
&& \tag{P'13}
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[2][1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wanna make a new environment `myalignedat` to typeset centered and aligned equations like my MWE such that instead of typing

```
\begin{<display math mode environment>}
    \adjintertext{0pt}{12pt}{\centering%
     \(\begin{alignedat}{2}
     & \text{(i) }   & a &= b, \\
     & \text{(ii) }  & a &< b, \\
     & \text{(iii) } & b &< a.
    \end{alignedat}\)%
}
\end{<display math mode environment>}
```

I would type the following instead:

```
\begin{<display math mode environment>}
    \begin{myalignedat}{2}[before skip=0pt, after skip=12pt]
        & \text{(i) }   & a &= b, \\
        & \text{(ii) }  & a &< b, \\
        & \text{(iii) } & b &< a.
    \end{myalignedat}
\end{<display math mode environment>}
```

similar to how the [`tcolorbox`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) does it for its environments.

My question is: ***How can I define such an environment?***

I've tried using `\newenviron` or the `environ` and `xparse` packages but to no avail since I have little knowledge about the matter. Thank you.

Comment: At this point in time, I would say that the cleanest solution would be [l3keys from the LaTeX3 interface](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), which has become an integral part of LaTeX. Alternatively, if you dislike this syntax, have a look at `pgfkeys`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Original answer

For this to work we have to somehow get the `\noalign` at a position where TeX finds it (inside of the `\begin{myalignedat}` definition seems too late for this). Therefore the following uses the `env/myalignedat/before` and `env/myalignedat/after` hooks along with some brace trick (`` \ifnum0=`{ `` and `` \ifnum0=`} ``) to get the `\noalign` to where we need it. Also we need to reimplement the `\adjintertext` code in our environment.

Once we have that out of our way the rest is pretty straight forward, we just collect an optional and a mandatory argument and use any `key=val` implementation that fits our needs (the following uses `expkv` with the `expkv-def` key-defining frontend<sup>1</sup>, but other packages would work as well). Another small adjustment (that one isn't really necessary though) is that the following doesn't use `\begin{alignedat}...\end{alignedat}` but `\alignedat...\endalignedat` instead.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,DIV=12]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \adjintertext custom spacing \intertext macro (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280847/228055)
    \MHInternalSyntaxOn
    \newcommand{\adjintertext}[3]% #1=above skip, #2=below skip, #3=text
    {\ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
      \noalign{%
        %\penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\belowdisplayskip
        \vskip-\lineskiplimit      % CCS
        \vskip\normallineskiplimit % CCS
        \vskip#1
        \vbox{\normalbaselines
            \ifdim
            \ifdim\@totalleftmargin=\z@
                \linewidth
            \else
                -\maxdimen
            \fi
            =\columnwidth
            \else \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
            \fi
        \noindent#3\par}%
        %\penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayskip%
        \vskip-\lineskiplimit      % CCS
        \vskip\normallineskiplimit % CCS
        \vskip#2
    }}%
    \MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\usepackage{expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{myalignedat}
  {
     skip before skip = \myalignedat@before
    ,skip after skip  = \myalignedat@after
  }
\AddToHook{env/myalignedat/before}
  {\ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi}
\AddToHook{env/myalignedat/after}
  {\ifnum0=`{\fi}}
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\newenvironment{myalignedat}[2][]
  {%
    \ekvset{myalignedat}{#1}%
    \vskip\myalignedat@before
    \vbox\bgroup\normalbaselines
      \ifdim
        \ifdim\@totalleftmargin=\z@
          \linewidth
        \else
          -\maxdimen
        \fi
        =\columnwidth
      \else
        \parshap\@ne\@totalleftmargin \linewidth
      \fi
      \noindent
      \centering\(\alignedat{#2}%
  }
  {%
      \endalignedat\)%
    \par\egroup
    \vskip-\lineskiplimit
    \vskip\normallineskiplimit
    \vskip\myalignedat@after
  }
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}

\lipsum[1][1-6]
\begin{flalign*}
& \text{For any numbers \(a\)}
&& \tag{P'10} \\
%%%%% the part related to the question %%%%%
\begin{myalignedat}[before skip=0pt, after skip=12pt]{2}
   & \text{(i) }   & a &= b, \\
   & \text{(ii) }  & a &< b, \\
   & \text{(iii) } & b &< a.
\end{myalignedat}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\) and \(b < c\), then \(a < c\).}
&& \tag{P'11} \\
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\), then \(a + c < b + c\).}
&& \tag{P'12} \\
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\) abd \(0 < c\), then \(ac < bc\).}
&& \tag{P'13}
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[2][1-8]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

<sup><sup>1</sup>Disclaimer: I'm the package author of `expkv` and friends</sup>

---

## Improved version needing to hack `\begin`

The above code version couldn't detect whether a `\\` was used before it or not, and thus lead to inconsistent vertical spacing. The following fixes that by patching LaTeX's `\begin` to have another hook. The patch should be fine and not affect any other usage of `\begin`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,DIV=12]{scrbook}

\makeatletter
% redefine `\begin` to have another hook. This hook is no generic hook, so we
% have to use `\NewHook{env/#1/evenbeforebefore}` before we can use `\AddToHook`
% on it (for each environment that needs it)
\edef\begin#1%
  {%
    \unexpanded
      {%
        \ifx\protect\relax
        \else
          \expandafter\@gobbletwo
        \fi
      }%
    \noexpand\UseHook{env/#1/evenbeforebefore}%
    \noexpand\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname begin \endcsname{#1}%
  }
\makeatother

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\usepackage{expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{myalignedat}
  {
     skip before skip = \myalignedat@before
    ,skip after skip  = \myalignedat@after
  }
\NewHook{env/myalignedat/evenbeforebefore}
\AddToHook{env/myalignedat/evenbeforebefore}
  {\ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi}
\AddToHook{env/myalignedat/after}
  {\ifnum0=`{\fi}}
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\newenvironment{myalignedat}[2][]
  {%
    \ekvset{myalignedat}{#1}%
    \vskip\myalignedat@before
    \vbox\bgroup\normalbaselines
      \ifdim
        \ifdim\@totalleftmargin=\z@
          \linewidth
        \else
          -\maxdimen
        \fi
        =\columnwidth
      \else
        \parshap\@ne\@totalleftmargin \linewidth
      \fi
      \noindent
      \centering\(\alignedat{#2}%
  }
  {%
      \endalignedat\)%
    \par\egroup
    \vskip-\lineskiplimit
    \vskip\normallineskiplimit
    \vskip\myalignedat@after
  }
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}

\lipsum[1][1-6]
\begin{flalign*}
& \text{For any numbers \(a\) with much text following it}
&& \tag{P'10} \\
%%%%% the part related to the question %%%%%
\begin{myalignedat}[before skip=0pt, after skip=0pt]{2}
   & \text{(i) }   & a &= b, \\
   & \text{(ii) }  & a &< b, \\
   & \text{(iii) } & b &< a.
\end{myalignedat}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\) and \(b < c\), then \(a < c\).}
&& \tag{P'11} \\
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\), then \(a + c < b + c\).}
&& \tag{P'12} \\
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\) abd \(0 < c\), then \(ac < bc\).}
&& \tag{P'13}
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[2][1-8]

\end{document}
```

---

## Pseudo-environment version

This version uses a fully expandable macro to start a pseudo-environment. It doesn't require any hacking of standard LaTeX macros, but it still uses the brace hacks. It expands to `\noalign` directly and can then use unexpandable argument grabbing and key=value parsing.

The environment is started by `\beginmyalignedat[<key=value>]{<alignedat-arg>}` and ended by `\stopmyalignedat`.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,DIV=12]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{expkv-def}

\makeatletter
\ekvdefinekeys{myalignedat}
  {
     skip before skip = \myalignedat@before
    ,skip after skip  = \myalignedat@after
  }
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\newcommand*\beginmyalignedat
  {%
    \ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
    \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
      \myalignedat@
  }
\newcommand\myalignedat@[2][]
  {%
      \ekvset{myalignedat}{#1}%
      \vskip-\lineskiplimit
      \vskip\normallineskiplimit
      \vskip\myalignedat@before
      \vbox\bgroup
        \normalbaselines
        \ifdim
          \ifdim\@totalleftmargin=\z@
            \linewidth
          \else
            -\maxdimen
          \fi
          =\columnwidth
        \else
          \parshape\@ne\@totalleftmargin\linewidth
        \fi
        \noindent
        \centering
        $\begin{alignedat}{#2}%
  }
\newcommand\stopmyalignedat
  {%
        \end{alignedat}$%
        \par
        \vskip-\lineskiplimit
        \vskip\normallineskiplimit
        \vskip\myalignedat@after
      \egroup
    \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
  }
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}

\lipsum[1][1-6]
\begin{flalign*}
& \text{For any numbers \(a\)}
&& \tag{P'10} \\
%%%%% the part related to the question %%%%%
\beginmyalignedat[after skip=12pt]{2}
   & \text{(i) }   & a &= b, \\
   & \text{(ii) }  & a &< b, \\
   & \text{(iii) } & b &< a.
\stopmyalignedat
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\) and \(b < c\), then \(a < c\).}
&& \tag{P'11} \\
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\), then \(a + c < b + c\).}
&& \tag{P'12} \\
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\) abd \(0 < c\), then \(ac < bc\).}
&& \tag{P'13}
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[2][1-8]

\end{document}
```

---

## Normal macro version

A macro variant that just grabs the arguments in an expandable way, uses an expandable key=value interface, and hence "directly" expands to `\adjintertext`, such that it behaves as if `\adjintertext` was used like in your code. An alternative version could use the same brace trick like the other solutions to use non-expandable argument grabbing and key=value solutions.

The syntax is:

```
\myalignedat[<key=val>]{<alignedat-arg>}{<alignedat-content>}
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,DIV=12]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \adjintertext custom spacing \intertext macro (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280847/228055)
    \MHInternalSyntaxOn
    \newcommand{\adjintertext}[3]% #1=above skip, #2=below skip, #3=text
    {\ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
      \noalign{%
        %\penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\belowdisplayskip
        \vskip-\lineskiplimit      % CCS
        \vskip\normallineskiplimit % CCS
        \vskip#1
        \vbox{\normalbaselines
            \ifdim
            \ifdim\@totalleftmargin=\z@
                \linewidth
            \else
                -\maxdimen
            \fi
            =\columnwidth
            \else \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
            \fi
        \noindent#3\par}%
        %\penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayskip%
        \vskip-\lineskiplimit      % CCS
        \vskip\normallineskiplimit % CCS
        \vskip#2
    }}%
    \MHInternalSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{expkv-cs}

% grabbing an optional argument expandable
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\myalignedat{O{} m m}
  {%
    % forward all arguments to \myalignedatKV
    \myalignedatKV{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }
% splitting the first argument into two arguments based on a key=value interface
\ekvcSplitAndForward\myalignedatKV\myalignedatDO
  {
     before skip=0pt
    ,after  skip=0pt
  }
% grabbing all the arguments and setting the output
\newcommand\myalignedatDO[4]
  {%
    \adjintertext{#1}{#2}
      {%
        \centering
        $%
        \begin{alignedat}{#3}
          #4%
        \end{alignedat}%
        $%
      }%
  }

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}

\lipsum[1][1-6]
\begin{flalign*}
& \text{For any numbers \(a\)}
&& \tag{P'10} \\
%%%%% the part related to the question %%%%%
\myalignedat[after skip=12pt]{2}
  {
     & \text{(i) }   & a &= b, \\
     & \text{(ii) }  & a &< b, \\
     & \text{(iii) } & b &< a.
  }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\) and \(b < c\), then \(a < c\).}
&& \tag{P'11} \\
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\), then \(a + c < b + c\).}
&& \tag{P'12} \\
& \text{For any numbers \(a\), \(b\), and \(c\), if \(a < b\) abd \(0 < c\), then \(ac < bc\).}
&& \tag{P'13}
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[2][1-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Just one little thing though, compared to my MWE, it seems that there's some extra vertical space even when `before skip=0pt`. Is there a way to have the preceding vertical spacing similar to my example?

Comment: @FarrelAhmed I think that the `\ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi` doesn't work correctly. If you omit the `\\ ` before `\begin{myalignedat}` the spacing should be correct. I'm not yet sure what's causing this.

Comment: Ah I see, if possible I really want the preceding and succeeding vertical space to be at least roughly if not exactly equivalent when `before skip=0pt` and `after skip=0pt`

Comment: @FarrelAhmed as long as you don't want to switch to a macro, I'm afraid there isn't much I can do about the space inconsistency. Either don't ever use `\\ ` before the environment (it'll do so itself) or don't use an environment. The problem is that even the `env/myalignedat/before` hook is only executed after a new align-row was started (`\begin` is defined using the `\protect` mechanism), hence there is nothing I can do about this. If on the other hand a macro grabbing those arguments would be fine (so e.g. instead of `\begin{myalignedat}` using `\beginmyalignedat`) I could probably fix this

Comment: @FarrelAhmed the alternative would be changing the definition of `\begin` (I'm relatively sure that it is safe, but not sure whether it's a good idea).

Comment: If you don't mind, do you think you can temporary change the definition of `\begin` then redefine it to be the default after? Or is that still not the best idea? (I can accept your answer already if you want, though)

Comment: @FarrelAhmed a temporary redefinition wouldn't solve the issue as that can't be done expandably and hence doesn't solve our issue at hand. I can post the code with the redefinition of `\begin` though (it should be safe).

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry but I could not compile my document using the new code as it gives a lot of errors.

Comment: @FarrelAhmed is your TeX Live installation up to date? Which kind of errors? Please note that I only test my answers against the most recent TeX Live (2022 in this case) and I update that at least weekly. If the above doesn't work you should switch from an environment to a command (or a command-version of an environment with a `\beginmyalignedat ...\stopmyalignedat` pair -- names not fixed). If you want I could provide both (but I might need some time to find time doing that)

Comment: @FarrelAhmed and forget about my comment directly above. I made a small change (that I didn't test) that broke stuff. The version patching `\begin` should work now.

Comment: I'm compiling on Overleaf which I do believe should use the latest TeX Live distribution

Comment: If you don't mind, yes please, could you provide that? I'm willing to wait, because right now my best personal solution is to just use a code snippet shortcut for `\adjintertext{<before skip>}{<after skip>}{\centering\(\begin{alignedat}{<num>} <aligned math> \end{alignedat}\)}` when I'm using a Text Editor like VS Code which I don't mind though I'm still looking to see if I can define a new environment as per my question. Thanks in advance and for everything so far!

Comment: @FarrelAhmed I already provided those other versions 22h ago :P There is my "original answer", the "improved version" (which hacks `\begin`), the "pseudo-environment" version (that's the one using `\beginmyalignedat` and `\stopmyalignedat`), and a "macro version" (that's the one using normal arguments). (my answer now has 4 sections with the respective solution)