# Left align text in equation environment (no use of align environment)

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I understand that you can left-align text using `\intertext{...}` inside `\begin{align}...\end{align}` environment, e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1667/2720).

Is it possible to do the same but inside `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`?

The end goal is to wrap the whole environment inside a display formula (`\[ \]`) as part of bullet point within a list. I've tried wrapping the `align` environment this way, but for some reason `\intertext{...}` does not work as the text is squeezed together without spaces.

EDIT: clarifying the question with an example and more context.

First, I should say that I'm trying to do this in `org-mode` in `Emacs`, i.e. compiling a `org` doc a PDF via `LaTeX`. The equations appear as part of an item in a list, e.g.

```
- Blah blah blah, then \[\begin{align*} \label{eq1} \text{something text}
   &= \frac{a}{b} \\ &= \frac{a}{c+d} \\ & \intertext{some other text, gives}
   \\ \label{eq2} a &= b+c \end{align*}\]
```

In other words, I want the block of displayed equations to be centered w.r.t the list item they belong to, and I want the `intertext{...}` text to be left-aligned w.r.t the start of each *list item*, or, at least to the left edge of the *displayed formula block*.

At the top of the `.org` doc, I have

```
#+OPTIONS: TeX:t LaTeX:t
#+LaTeX_CLASS: article
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{amsmath}
```

So far, `Emacs` seems to compile and produces a PDF file, except that the `\intertext` segment inside the display formula is wrong:

[image]

How do I correct it? I am also open to suggestions that utilize something other than a single `\begin{align}...\end{align}` environment to achieve the same effect inside a list item.

Comment: `align` and  `equation` are both displayed environments for math.

Comment: Could you give an example of "`\intertext{...}` [not working] as the text is squeezed together without spaces"?

Comment: `align` is a _multi-line_ display and `\intertext` inserts lines of text _between_ the lines of math. `equation` is a _single line_ display so `\intertext` would have no obvious use here.

Comment: your description of `\intertext` suggests it has been used incorrectly but unless you give an example it will be impossible to help.

Comment: the question of left-aligning an equation as part of a bulleted list is addressed in this answer to the question [Vertical alignment of align* in enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54686/579).  while that answer directly addresses a multi-line equation, the principle is also applicable to a one-line equation, but the equation *must* be entered with a command for a "subsidiary" environment, not with `\[ ... \]` or `equation`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the comments. I have updated the question with more details, and hopefully we can work out what goes wrong here.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the comment. I have updated the question with more details, and hopefully we can work out what goes wrong here.

Comment: `\intertext` only makes sense after `\\ ` not after `&` it goes _between rows_ but  in general please _always_ provide a complete small document that shows the problem, it is impossible to debug disconnected fragments.

Comment: `align*` _starts_ math mode so you must have had multiple tex errors from  `\[\begin{align*}`   you can not have `align*` inside math. After a TeX error you should not even look at the pdf file, tex recovers from errors to allow further syntax checking, it makes no attempt to make sensible typeset output in that case.

Answer (score 3):

If I complete your fragment to make a document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Blah blah blah, then \[\begin{align*} \label{eq1} \text{something text}
   &= \frac{a}{b} \\ &= \frac{a}{c+d} \\ & \intertext{some other text, gives}
   \\ \label{eq2} a &= b+c \end{align*}\]

\end{document}
```

then TeX produces

```
! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7    \\ \label{eq2} a &= b+c \end{align*}
                                           \]
? 

! Package amsmath Error: Invalid use of \intertext.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7    \\ \label{eq2} a &= b+c \end{align*}
                                           \]
? 

! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq1' will be lost.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7    \\ \label{eq2} a &= b+c \end{align*}
                                           \]
? 
[1
```

After an error any typeset output that may be produced is essentially arbitrary and not really to be looked at, TeX recovers from errors only to allow further syntax checking, usually the typeset result is nonsense.

If I fix the errors reported namely `align*` should not be inside `\[`, `\intertext` should be at the start of the line and you shouldn't use `\label` as the `*` form is not numbered so there is nothing to reference, I get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Blah blah blah, then
\begin{align*}  \text{something text}
   &= \frac{a}{b} \\ &= \frac{a}{c+d} \\
\intertext{some other text, gives}
   \\ a &= b+c 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. `\intertext{...}` does display the text now, but its positioning is still off. How do I make it aligned to the start of the list item, e.g. 'Blah blah ...' in my example above.

Comment: @Skyork it is aligned with the left margin of the text, `Blah` is just to the right due to being the start of a paragraph.

Comment: @Skyork if you want to ask about usage in a list your example should have a complete document as above but showing usage in an `enumerate` or `itemize` or whatever list you need. Can't expect people to guess.