# Achieving captioning with align blocks

Tags: table-of-contents, equations, captions, align, subcaption

I have code like this:

```
\begin{align}
  c_{i,p} = \frac{c_{i,p}}{IQR(c_{i})}\label{eq:1}\\  
  c_{i,p} = \frac{c_{i,p})}{Median(c_{i})}\label{eq:1}\\  
  c_{i,p} = \frac{c_{i,p})}{MAD(c_{i})}\label{eq:1}\\  
  c_{i,p} = \frac{c_{i,p})}{max(c_{i,p})-c_{i,p}}\label{eq:1}\\  
  c_{i,p} = \frac{c_{i,p})}{max(c_{i,p})-c_{i,p}}\label{eq:1}\\  
\end{align}
```

That looks like:

[image]

However, I came across the formatting of this textbook like so and would love to add captions in this way. There are two types of ways the author captions the formulas.

1. Each formula is in a block grid and each has a label between `(1)` to `(3)`. I want to achieve this and also allow captioning around the whole figure created so that it goes in my `\listoffigures`.
2. Each formula has its own `subsubsection number`. I want to achieve this too or at least see how it is done.

[image]

Comment: There's nothing fancy about the book typesetting. A list-like environment (perhaps sectioning) followed by a bunch of equations... Your little code snippet is a far cry from the look of the book, so it's not entire clear how you want to *caption* the equations and place these captions inside the `\listoffigures`. Can you elaborate? Perhaps draw a picture showing your expected output?

Comment: Maybe you need `\intertext` to break up the align with text.

Comment: Sigmund Freud would say: An equation is an equation, so why using a caption to make it appear in the `LoF`? What's the purpose of that?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: That would only make sense if the alignment needs to be preserved, and from the book view it seems not. And for that we have the following: [How can I add left aligned text to an equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1665/5764)

Comment: @Werner You are right the book does not show it; however, the OP seemed to emphasize the notion of breaking up an `align` block with text.  I guess some clarification from the OP would help.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Sigmund  analysed equations? ;o)

Comment: @Bernard: Sure, in Austria 'Calculus' is named 'Analysis' :-P He was in fact a `\Psi-cho-analysist` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Groan/smirk. :-)

Comment: @Mico: One bad joke a day keeps the doctor away ;-)

Comment: Or \Psi-\chi? It's also named « Analyse » in France (and, I suppose, in Greece!).

Comment: I absolutely love the LaTex stack exchange :)

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

- What you call "captions" of equations appear to be, in LaTeX jargon, nothing but `\paragraph`-level headers. To wit, it's straightforward to replicate the "look" of your textbook using `\paragraph` instructions; see also the code below.
- Use of the `\paragraph` approach provides a high degree of flexibility of where page breaks may occur. With an `align`-based approach, you'd have to worry about where to allow page breaks.
- In your textbook excerpt, the equations do *not* appear to be aligned relative to each other. Put differently, they are individually and independently centered on their respective lines. I suggest you use individual `equation` environments.

Aside: Since "IQR", "MAD", and "Median" would appear to be operators (in the TeX/LaTeX sense of the word), they should be typeset in upright letters. The `amsmath` package lets you create math operators via the `\DeclareMathOperator` directive. By the way, `\max` is already defined -- use it!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % default is "3" for article document class
% Paragraph-level headers: italic, not bold
\usepackage{sectsty}
\paragraphfont{\mdseries\itshape} 

\usepackage{amsmath} % for \DeclareMathOperator and \numberwithing macros
\DeclareMathOperator{\IQR}{IQR}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Median}{Median}
\DeclareMathOperator{\MAD}{MAD}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
% Just for this example:
\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{subsection}{2}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{23}
\setcounter{equation}{36}

\paragraph{Interquartile range}
\begin{equation}
  c_{i,p} = \frac{c_{i,p}}{\IQR(c_{i})}\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
\paragraph{Median}
\begin{equation} 
  c_{i,p} = \frac{c_{i,p}}{\Median(c_{i})}\label{eq:2}
\end{equation}
\paragraph{Minimum absolute distance}
\begin{equation} 
  c_{i,p} = \frac{c_{i,p}}{\MAD(c_{i})}\label{eq:3}
\end{equation}
\paragraph{Max 1}
\begin{equation} 
  c_{i,p} = \frac{c_{i,p}}{\max(c_{i,p})-c_{i,p}}\label{eq:4} 
\end{equation}
\paragraph{Max 2}
\begin{equation} 
  c_{i,p} = \frac{c_{i,p}}{\max(c_{i,p})-c_{i,p}}\label{eq:5}  
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Mico, for the first example in the textbook example, it seems like these are subcaptions e.g. (1), (2), (3)? How do I have it so all of those could be named using (1) (2) (3) and have a figure caption at the bottom of the group which maybe has "Figure 1: List of Cost Functions"? Which appears in my `listoffigures`?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati - Please note that "\caption" is something of a reserved word in LaTeX. For sure, even though the textbook would appear to have been generated by TeX and friends, nothing you describe as "captions" is generated via a `\caption` instruction. The `(1)`, `(2)`, etc almost certainly come for an enumerated list, i.e., `\begin{enumerate}` followed by `\item`, `\item` etc `\end{enumerate}`. Incidentally, I'm afraid I absolutely don't "get" why these formulas as supposed to be part of a `figure` environment. That's certainly not what the textbook excerpt is showing.

Comment: Understood. My goal is to have a grid of equations which each individually go into the list of equations I have (the index I create), but the overarching group of them appears as one thing in the list of figures.