# The align environment in amsart

Tags: equations, align, amsart

I am noticing that equations when written inside the ``align" environment in the amsart class document come with a lot of white space around it. Particularly if there is a single line sentence between 2 instances of the align environment then there is a very conspicuous amount of white space around that single line.

Can someone suggest a fix for this?

Comment: You can use a single align and `\intertext`  between the two aligned lines, if that is semantically meaningful.

Comment: Not sure how to do that when each block of align needs its own label for future referencing

Comment: Each line has its own label, that is no problem.  The real problem is; do the two lines have any reason to have a common alignment point.

Comment: But currently the 2 different align blocks have their own labels. There will be no way to maintain that if I merge them into a single align block with an intertext in between.

Comment: No, they do have their own number and label.

Comment: @gradstudent: See [How can I add left aligned text to an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1665/5764) That's what `\intertext` (and `\shortintertext` from [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)) are designed for.

Comment: Not sure how this is helping. I need 2 different labels on each of the align blocks. I see no way to maintain that if I use intertext and merge the 2 align blocks!

Comment: align labels per row there is no alignment for the display as a whole so why does using one alignment with `\intertext` for the sentence prevent you from having labels? Also you have not shown any input, excessive white space can be caused by several markup errors such as leaving a blank line before the alignment. It would clarify if you edited the question to show a small complete document with the problem,

Comment: @gradstudent: I've closed your question. If you feel that this was a mistake, please edit your question (by clicking on the edit button below the question) and update it with the necessary details. Of course, take into consideration the current answer in doing so.

Answer (score 3):

The intended markup for a sentence of text mid-alignment is `\intertext` or for even tighter spacing you can use `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa 
aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa 
\begin{align}
  1&=2\\
  2&=3\\
\shortintertext{some one line sentence text goes here}
 3&=4\\
5&=6
\end{align}
aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa 
aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. (a) You arent using the "amsart" class. Maybe this is a specific issue with how amsart and align interact to produce a lot of white space before the beginning and after the ending of the align?  (b) I cannot use intertext because that will then need me to merge the 2 align environments while I need separate labels for each of them for future referencing.

Comment: I need to have the format as, 
\begin{align}\ref{eq1}
  1&=2\\
  2&=3\\ 
\end{align}
some one line sentence text goes here,
\begin{align}\ref{eq2}
 3&=4\\
5&=6
\end{align}

Comment: @gradstudent, please edit your question and provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) which show your problem. This answer also with use of `amsart` gives the same result: no extra white space around equations.

Comment: @gradstudent as we said multiple times in comments under the question you are mistaken about `\label`, label applies to a singe row of the alignment and you can have one on every row.