# Keeping lines centered and a word left adjusted

Tags: equations, align

How do I do this? How can I keep "and" on the far left like that?
[image]

Comment: I'd simply remove “and”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % or \usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
               && Z\cap W &= \{ y \in W: g_1(y) = 0, \ldots, g_l(y) = 0 \} & \\
    \text{and} && X\cap W &= \{ y \in W: g_1(y) = 0, \ldots, g_m(y) = 0 \},
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

which gives you

[image: result]

Some additional information can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1667/234654) if you wish possibly some changes.
In brief, the `&` next to `=` is the main equation we want to be aligned.
The `&&` on the left part creates an empty column that is essential to the alignment of the text. The `&` on the right ensures the main equation sits in the center.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a different solution idea: (a) place "and" on a line between the two equations (using the `\shortintertext` macro) and (b) employ an `alignat*{2}` to take care of aligning all `=` symbols vertically.

If you really do want to place the "and" particle on the second row instead of between the rows, I wouldn't move the word all the way to the left-hand margin; a separation by `\qquad` ("double \quad") seems more natural. In the code below, I use `\llap{and\qquad}` to make sure that the presence of the word "and" doesn't affect the (horizontal) centering of the equations -- after all, you've stated the requirement "keeping lines centered" in the title of your query. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}           % for \shortintertext macro
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times Roman text and math font)
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
   Z \cap W &= \{ y \in W : g_1(y) = 0, \dots,   & g_l(y) &= 0 \} \\
\shortintertext{and}
   X \cap W &= \{ y \in W : g_1(y) = 0, \dots,{} & g_m(y) &= 0 \} \,,
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
   Z \cap W &= \{ y \in W : g_1(y) = 0, \dots,   & g_l(y) &= 0 \} \\
\llap{and\qquad}
   X \cap W &= \{ y \in W : g_1(y) = 0, \dots,{} & g_m(y) &= 0 \} \,,
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility with the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{nccmath} % loads amsmath
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}

    \lipsum[11]
    \begin{fleqn}
    \begin{align*}
                   && Z\cap W &= \{ y \in W: g_1(y) = 0, \ldots, g_l(y) = 0 \} \\
         & \text{and} & X\cap W &= \{ y \in W: g_1(y) = 0, \ldots, g_m(y) = 0 \},
    \end{align*}
    \end{fleqn}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. I think they are better than what I did. Because what if I wanted to `\tag` something on the right side also. But I just used a **left tag**. `\newcommand{\leqnos}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}`

```
{ 
\leqnos
\begin{align*}
&{Z} \cap  {W}= \{ {y} \in  {W} :  {g}_{1}({y})={0}  ,  \ldots, {g}_{l({y})={0}  \} 
\\
\tag*{and}
&{X} \cap  {W}=\{ {y} \in  {W} :  {g}_{1}({y})={0}   ,     \ldots, {g}_{m}({y})={0} \}
,
\end{align*}
}
```